# Java's interactive shell like ipython

Tags: java, shell

I am quite new to Java and would like to learn Java using an interactive shell, like I did with Python using IPython.

I have tried a few interactive shells, such as beanshell, jython, jythonconsole, and JyConsole. Most of them don't have tab completion like IPython does. Is there anything similar to IPython for java?

Comment: +1 because I'm not sure whether such a shell exists, but it would be useful. (I nearly posted BeanShell before I took a moment to read the second paragraph.)

Comment: JShell is a standard component of JDK since Java 9. Try running `$jshell` on a terminal.

Answer (score 10):

**groovysh**:

http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+Shell

- Rich cross-platform edit-line editing, history and completion thanks to JLine.
- ANSI colors (prompt, exception traces, etc).
- Simple, yet robust, command system with online help, user alias support and more.
- User profile support

Answer (score 9):

If you want an interactive option for use with java try using Dr Java or JGrasp, they both provide the same interactive option as does IDLE for python, plus being a fully based IDE with a debugger I prefer JGrasp to Dr Java.  They also have a Dr Python so if  you get used to Dr Java you can also use it with Python.

Also Dr Java has a feature in which you can select from beginner, intermediate, advanced and full Java in order to limit what you can do with the language as you learn it.  I never use that feature as I dont see the point in restricting parts of the langaue but I guess some teachers utilize it while teaching their students.

Answer (score 8):

You probably won't get much use out of using java interactively, as that language is strongly oriented toward compiling.  The best route will probably just get a nice IDE, like [eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/), and get started with breakpoints and the debugger.

Comment: I actually use Beanshell quite often, lately beanshell 2 (http://code.google.com/p/beanshell2/).  However, I have not found a variety with code completion.

Comment: I didn't mean to say that its impossible, or even non-useful to use Java interactively.  I have used and enjoy some C++ interpreters for various tasks.  But because these languages are not designed with such use in mind, you don't get the same level of utility as you would with more interactive oriented languages like python.

Comment: If you tried beanshell, it extended java to be more scripting language like, in which you don't have to declare the variable type. There are much more advantages like closure, but I just started using that.

Comment: In fairness, Python is also an OO language and iPython (et al) work beautifully. I will agree that it's more convenient not needing to specify your type all the time (as you would in iJava) but that's no reason an interactive shell wouldn't work.

Comment: You should replace eclipse with intellij.

Comment: @Bruno: I'm not too interested in IDE's,  My favorite IDE is I don't use an IDE ever.  As such, I'm not really making a recommendation for one ide or another.

Comment: "The best route will probably just get a nice IDE, like eclipse, and get started with breakpoints and the debugger." In what context is that not a recommendation for eclipse?

Answer (score 3):

what beanshell have you used ? the old one ?
Look at [this](http://ikayzo.org/confluence/display/BSH/Netbeans+and+Beanshell) 
they claim to provide completion

Comment: I am now using eclipse instead of netbean, since I am also coding other languages like python and c++. I just use beanshell from http://www.beanshell.org/

Answer (score 3):

Gayan Weerakutti already mentioned in a comment what I think should be the correct answer, too: 
JShell is part of the JDK since version 9.
Try `jshell` on your terminal. 
Check out [docs from Oracle about it](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/jshell/introduction-jshell.htm#JSHEL-GUID-630F27C8-1195-4989-9F6B-2C51D46F52C8).

Answer (score 2):

I think I find a good enough alternative: JPype. JPype allows python programs having full access to java class libraries. With JPype and IPython, I can use all java functions while having very nice tab completion for the java classes.(After the class is imported though)

Answer (score 1):

Although I agree with *TokenMacGuy* saying:

> The best route will probably just get a nice IDE, like eclipse

As Im also coming from environment where tool like interactive shell was essential. So I can also suggest you simply using tool like [ipython](http://ipython.scipy.org/moin/) directly from [jython](http://www.jython.org/2.)/JPype.

That can be achieved or using [JPype](http://jpype.sourceforge.net/) as suggested by *i-freaker* of through jython:

1. Getting `jython` (check its running `jython -c 'import os; print "Python meets %s" % os.name'`)
2. Getting `readrline` (In case Mac `sudo port install readline`)
3. Fallowing the steps from [this blog](http://bravo5.org/blog/2004/08/30/getting-java-readline-to-work-on-os-x/) or [jython documentation](http://wiki.python.org/jython/ReadlineSetup3.) to make j`ava-readline` work
4. So you have `jython` with `readline` by now(`Ctrl+R` in jython results in `reverse-i-search` like you know it from the shell). In order to get tab-completion like you know it form `ipython` fallow the steps from [this blog](http://blog.secretr.org/2009/11/4/How_to_use_IPython_with_Jython/)
5. That should be it! In case you need patch for ipython 0.10 you can [get it from here](http://tinyurl.com/378q7qd).

Answer (score 0):

Give a look at https://github.com/Bachmann1234/java9_kernel you can install a Java kernel for IPython and use it (also via the notebook).

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ IDEA has a groovy console with tab completion.

open it: Tools -> Groovy Console...